# As the IntentService complete its job. is it possible to start another thread from UI thread but not from activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intentservice

IntentService has its own thread, starting another thread from handleIntent, the service considered  live or completed service and doesn't matter another thread is active or nor?
and as soon as the IntentService completed its job ,is it possible to return to main thread and call another thread, but the start of the another thread  could be from main thread not from activity, as the service could complete its job during any active activity.

Answer (score 0):

> IntentService has its own thread, starting another thread from
>   handleIntent

Don't ever do that. Once the `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()` method returns, the service is destroyed and the process is likely to be killed as well. Android has no idea what threads you've started so for all it knows your process is idle and wasting resources.

If you need to "start" something else when the `IntentService` is done, use `startActivity()`, `startService()` or `sendBroadcast()` (whichever is appropriate). Again, Android doesn't know about your threads.

If you need procedure call semantics (e.g, start service, have it perform some task, then return control to the caller), `IntentService` isn't the right tool. Use a bound service (or bound AIDL service if you need to cross process boundaries).

Comment: Thanks ,I got the first part,
as soon as the IntentService complete it's job, receiving appropriate data, I need to start another thread, the point is the the second thread I need to start from main thread , but I don't want that the receiver for the completion of IntentService be the activity ,as the completion of IntentService could be during any active activity, I want smth, global place, that can handle IntentService completion ,where I could start another thread.

Comment: Don't do that. You should never create threads from an `IntentService`. I can't really help here since you are just making statements like "the second thread I need to start from main thread" with no explanation why.

Comment: Ok the point is that I use library which implements downloading mechanism,   but before starting the second  I need to fetch resources and as soon I receive result start 2_n thread(which handles downloading mechanism)
and take into account that the first thread should continue it's job even I leave the activity. that is why I wanted to use IntentService
any advise could be helpful, thanks

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to run whatever that is from the "main thread".

Comment: I use Glide and use Glide for only caching images, not displaying ,the issue is that it's only let to call from main thread.

Comment: I fetch resources then start downloading/caching via Glide,and even leaving the process should continue the process even I leave the activity, and when the resources are downloaded, it should fetch for other portion of resources and then start download/cache.

Comment: Don't use an `IntentService`. Use a regular `Service`. All service lifecycle methods run on the main thread. You can start threads from the service to your heart's content.

Comment: ok ,Thanks .
you mean to use Service instead of IntentService, as it's run on main thread, but I need to fetch resources,which need to be implemented in separate thread,
or could it be good to start intentService fetch resource urls ,then after it finished it's job start service where I could start 2_nd thread?

Comment: No, use a `Service`, and from within that service, start whatever threads you need.

Comment: ok from Service start thread where I could fetch resources ,then I need to return to main thread( how the connection should be, and as I don't want to start the second thread from specified activity.Is it possible from Service ,where I start thread as soon as its finished its job return  to main thread, some general place ,where to start 2_nd thread
again thanks,any idea could be useful